# Why can't I upload an image and data with retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Regards, I have to upload this data.

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysumT.png)

And I have this code.

Customer Creation

```
public  BeeMappingClient(String url){

    retrofit= new  Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    conexion=retrofit.create(Conexion.class);
}
```

Interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("task")
Call<ResponsetTask> API_Task(@Header("Authorization") String key,
                             @Part MultipartBody.Part multipartImage,
                             @Part("message") RequestBody message ,
                             @Part("filecomment") RequestBody filecomment,
                             @Part("api_token") RequestBody api_token,
                             @Part("user_id") RequestBody user_id);
```

And call

```
File file=new File(path);

    MultipartBody.Part[] multipartImageList = new MultipartBody.Part[1];
    RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    multipartImageList[0] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image.jpg", surveyBody);
    RequestBody message = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("message"), Constantes.MESSAGE);
    RequestBody filecomment = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("filecomment"), Constantes.FILECOMMENT);
    RequestBody api_token = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("api_token"),Constantes.api_token);
    RequestBody user_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("user_id"), Integer.toString(Constantes.id));

    Call<ResponsetTask> call = conexion.API_Task(Constantes.AUTH,multipartImageList[0],message,filecomment,api_token,user_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsetTask>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsetTask> call, Response<ResponsetTask> response) {
            Constantes.api_task=response.body().getTaskId();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsetTask> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is that it does nothing, if I do a debug all seems to be going well until it reaches the call.enqueu ... there I should enter OnResques or OnFailure but it does not just go to the end of the method as if it did not exist .
What should I do ?, this is the best method to upload this data ?.
I thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this - for multipart request**

In *interface*

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("task")
    Call<ResponseBody> submitRegistration(@Part MultipartBody.Part body,
    @Part("message") RequestBody message)
```

Pass values -

```
    File file = new File(path);        
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
    RequestBody message = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Constantes.MESSAGE);
```

Call -

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.callApi(body,message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
```

Replace "image/*"  with "multipart/form-data"